# How to stop an iframe from reloading when the web page is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a simple web page (HTML/JavaScript/CSS/JQuery) that hosts an iframe inside it. The iframe source is a WebRTC-based softphone that a user logs in by providing extension and password, and once successful it displays telephony controls inside the iframe.

The problem is that when the web page is refreshed, the user inside the WebRTC client is logged out. I wonder if there is a way to stop the iframe to reload when the web page is refreshed?

I'm new to web development so not sure how to achieve this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Widget</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="widget.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe
      name="myframe"
      style="position: fixed; right:5px; bottom: 5px; height: 452px; width: 
      324px;"
      src="https://mywebserver/widget.html">          
    </iframe>
  </body>      

</html>
```

Comment: Short answer, no. Long answer, not without a workaround. I suggest not using an iframe and setting it up as another tab if possible.

Comment: You can't, reloading the page will unload everything. If you have control over the iframe contents (the softphone app), you might want to review how it's doing authentication.

Comment: Thanks @RichardBarker. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph - much appreciated your thoughts